# Sub folders within Git repository is not known to Git

Tags: git

I have created a Git repository locally and I have created a remote repository and made it bare `git --bare init` and from my local working copy folder I initialized it as a git folder. I ran `git remote add origin /path/to/remote` and I was able to run `git add .` and then commit all changes.

When I am in the local working folder and cd into a sub folder I notice I no longer have (master) at the end of my prompt and when I run `git show-ref` I get nothing returned. I think when I committed all the files somehow the contents within my sub folders were not recognized? When I run `git add subfolder/` and run `git status` I have nothing to commit because no changes have been found but it is recognized that it has been put into git?

Anyone have an idea what I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't know the folder unless exists as minimum a file within that folder, because git work with pointers to files.

Comment: I created an angular-fire project using Yeoman and haven't done any coding yet. I committed everything under the root folder to the project which includes the app/ folder and all the contents of it which is the real project. Going into app/ folder none of it seems to be included in the Git repository.

Comment: If the forlders are empty GIT doesn't recongnize the folder, it's its particularity.

Comment: app/ is not empty. If you create a web app using Yeoman the folders in app have index.html and several other subfolders like styles/ etc...

Comment: mmm. So try this: from a terminal type the command "git add * ", you must locate into the root directory of your project , it adds  any changes or files that exists into your project.

Comment: I have tried `git add *` and `git add .` from the root directory but it tells me that everything is up to date and there is nothing to commit. I don't know why it is ignoring some subfolders or how to force it to include them in Git.

Comment: That's very weird, the last option I think is try 'git status' only for seeing the state that it has. 

For forcing you must set 'git add * --force'.